# What's the command for Replace from Find in Files?

Tags: sublimetext2

I want to find the command for "Replace" (from the "Find in Files" panel) so that I can assign a keyboard shortcut to it.

Normally I can use `sublime.log_commands(True)` in the Console <kbd>Ctrl `</kbd> to identify the command, but the Console and Find in Files panels appear on top of each other; so I can't read the Console while I'm using Find in Files.

Comment: What would you be replacing with?  The clipboard contents?

Comment: @AGS - Whatever is in the Replace field in the Find All Files panel.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

From the default key bindings:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+enter"], "command": "replace_all", "args": {"close_panel": true},
     "context": [{"key": "panel", "operand": "replace"}, {"key": "panel_has_focus"}]
}
```